# Reproject Geotagged Photos

Tags: coordinate-system, geotag

Having hard time on how to geotagged photos on the reprojected shapefile. I have these photos and waypoints with GCS_WGS_1984 projection, in which coordinates are on decimal degrees. In this projection, I can still see the geotagged photos in its respective waypoints.

But when I reproject the shapefile (waypoints) from GCS_WGS_1984 to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_51N, my problem starts here.

1. I can't view the respective photos in its points.
2. Do I still need to reproject the coordinates of the photos? If so, how to reproject this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Transfer hyperlinks from original to projected

Answer (score 1):

> Do I still need to reproject the coordinates of the photos? If so, how
>   to reproject this?

You cannot reproject the coordinates of the geotagged photos and store them to the image metadata (`PropertyItem`). however your software may read those Lat/Long information and do some on the fly projection to bring them to the SRS that your shapefile reside. If this is not possible then on the fly projection must be applied on the shapefile and bring it to GCS_WGS_1984 (Geotagged photo SRS). This way both shapefile and Geotagged Photos will be in the same system.

For more information on how GPS data is stored in images you may see [this](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF). Below I provide a summary:

Location information is stored in image metadata as Latitude/Longitude with DMS format (Not exactly DMS format but with some conversion Degree Minute Seconds can be retrieved and then they can be converted into decimal degrees) so it is not possible to store location information in any other SRS in photos.

Comment: I reproject my shapefile to have the same coordinates system of my  waypoints and geotagged photos. Although, it's a bit tedious since I also need to reproject my other files to have a uniform system. But the important is it works and thanks a lot Hossein :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful; Anyway if you want to reproject geotagged images, one option is to develop your own software and read image coordinates and reproject those WGS84 coordinates to your interested SRS, however its not an easy option but if you want to try it I can give you a sample code on how to read coordinates from a Geotagged image file.